# Providing user login support on web for my application 

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a background in android development with almost no knowledge of server side implementations. I want to create an application wherein I can store user's data on the cloud (for example: user's call log or periodic gps location). I have had a look at parse.com features and it comes pretty close to what I need. Its especially attractive because of its ease of use and good documentation.

However, I need to provide the user access to this data from a web service as well (suppose the user doesn't have access to his/her phone). For this I need to create a user login support on my parse application page. Is it even possible to do that?

Also, I want to run some analysis on this data and present the user with this analysis through this online account.

Are there any other backend frameworks which can help me achieve this quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript SDK is officially supported by Parse, so you could not go wrong choosing that. However, if you'd like a server-side framework, check out the [3rd party libraries for the REST API](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries). Depending on your language preference, you should find something suitable to your needs there.

EDIT: You can also use the JavaScript SDK on the server with Node.js: http://blog.parse.com/2012/10/11/the-javascript-sdk-in-node-js/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parse for this. Parse provides both a [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest) and a [JavaScript SDK](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide) which you can use to create a companion web site for your mobile app.